# PHP MySQL Display a Row Based on if it doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql

So, I'm looking to display data from a table(courses) if the user's ID doesn't exist in a table(coursescompletion). The Code below is what I've tried, but any help would be greatly appreciated. "offname" is the User's ID, and I simplified it to simply "124" for whilst I test it. Cheers.

```
    $conn = getConnection();

            $res = getConnection()->query("SELECT * FROM courses LEFT JOIN coursescompletion ON coursescompletion.type=courses.Name WHERE coursescompletion.offname != '124'");

            if ($res->num_rows = 0) {
    
                while ($r=$res->fetch_assoc()) {


                    echo('

                    <tr>
                    <td >'. $r["Name"] .'</td>
                    <td >'. $r["Link"] .'</td>
                    <td >N/A</td>
                    <td >N/A</td>
                    <td >N/A</td>
                    </tr>

            ');

        }

    }
```

Edit. I updated the code, however it still doesn't work. Both the $res... and if ($res... lines

Edited Lines:

```
    $res = getConnection()->query("SELECT * FROM courses WHERE Name NOT IN (SELECT type FROM coursescompletion WHERE offname != '124')");

    if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
```

Comment: `$res->num_rows = 0` is an assignment, not a comparison (`==`). But also it's illogical to call `fetch_assoc()` after asserting there are no rows (nothing to fetch).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Just a guess (because you didn't provide a minimal reproducible example): wouldn't it rather be `$res = $conn()->query(...)`?